# Finding an eigenvector (fixed point) of a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fixed-points

I am currently studying for a test and often computation of large matrices (4x4 +) is expected.  More often than not there is a "quick" way to solve these such that a lot of hand computation is not necessary.  I worked through a practice problem with a given solution and the solution is much more efficient than mine, but I do not understand *why* the method used is valid and how to identify I could apply such a method.

Consider the system

$A\vec{x}=\frac{1}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}$.

To find the non trivial fixed point of the system, which is equivalent to the eigenvector for $\lambda=1$ the given solution is starts off like gaussian elimination and slowly considers smaller subsystems of the matrix, until reaching a 2x2 matrix which it solves for directly and then applies back substitution to find the eigenvector $\vec{x}^T=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$.

Here is an image of the full given solution [image: Solution1] [image: solution2].

What I don't understand is why is it valid to just consider the subsystem corresponding to rows 2-4?  I had expected The subsystem for rows 2-6 to be considered and row reduction repeated until the matrix is in upper triangular form and then apply back substitution.  It seems the method used here is similar to gaussian elimination (at least the form I am familiar with) but deviates.  I'd like to understand why / what's happening as it seems a lot more efficient than first putting the matrix into upper triangular form and then solving.

Comment: Once you have a column with a single nonzero entry, you can use column operations to zero out the corresponding row without affecting any of the other rows of the matrix. Those “outer” elements are still there, but to reduce clutter the solution elides them since none of the further operations will affect those elements of the matrix.

Comment: @amd, right but if you look after we have 0''s in the first column, the next subsystem we consider only contains rows 2,3,4 & 5 and omits row 6, which does not have a zero entry in the second column.  I don't get why this is valid.

Comment: Wait I get it.  I completely missed that the 6th column also has zeros in it.  All solved, no big mystery here.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're expected to do it quickly, here's a much quicker method. Any matrix where all the rows have equal sum $k$ will have $k$ as an eigenvalue and the vector of ones as the corresponding eigemvector. Since your matrix sums to 5 in each row and is multiplied by $1/5$, you can see the result immediately.

Comment: @dbx great tip, thanks!